# Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 699

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod

I'm debugging my application using my ipod touch. Two days before also I did the debugging. But from yesterday I can able to run the application with debug mode. Application also open basis on the debugging. After the application launched completely, after few seconds I got this error "Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 699." after that My Application get crashed. Please help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had problems debugging binaries on the device via XCode when the app includes an Entitlements.plist file, which is not necessary to install onto the device for debugging. In general, then, I have included this file for release builds (where it is required for the App Store) and removed it for debugging (so I can debug the app from XCode). That may be your problem here.

Update: As of (at least) August 2010 (iPhone 4.1 SDK) the Entitlements.plist is no longer necessary to include in your application in many cases (e.g., distribution through the App Store.) See here for more information on the cases when Entitlements.plist is required:

```
IMPORTANT: An Entitlements file is generally only needed when building for Ad Hoc Distribution or enabling Keychain data sharing. If neither of these is true, delete the entry in Code Signing Entitlements. (emphasis mine)
```

Also check your profile.

```
The ad-hoc profile doesn't support debugging. You need to debug with a Development profile, and use the Ad-Hoc profile only for distributing non-debuggable copies.
```

Comment: ya.. I'm using developer profile for debugging.. But it say the same problem

Comment: Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 768. Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 784.Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 752. The error for the process also varied. I don't understand the problem. Please make me clear....

Answer (score 0):

For xcode 4:you have to create Entitlements.plist file from new file. and
Targets->build Settings->Code Signing Entitlements you have to write here "Entitlements.plist"

I did this and xcode don not get anymore error