# Can't Launch Xcode App Without Code Signing on iPad, Can on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to deploy an Xcode app to my iPad without code signing. To do so, I have edit the SDKSettings.plist file, changed my project settings to do not run, and installed AppSync. This is the error I receive:

```
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 1019.
```

This is the error in the debug screen:

```
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 1396.The program being debugged is not being run.
```

The number keeps changing. On my iPhone, once I hit "ok" to dismiss the error on my computer, I can launch the app from the springboard and use it perfectly. However, on my iPad, this is not the case. It just crashes if I attempt to open it.

Has anyone ever had this program, or know how to solve it?

Also, my iPhone is on 5.0.1, and my iPad is on 5.1.1. The app works fine in the simulator, though.

Comment: Also, I am using debug on my scheme.

Comment: Are you using an Entitlements.plist file?

Comment: I'm very confused as to whether that is necessary. From what I have read, it is not at all necessary in debugging.

Comment: I don't think it is, but I saw that if you do have it, it could cause a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959645/error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-699

Comment: Saw that as well, I'm not using one.

Comment: Do you have a non-expired development provisioning profile? You probably already checked that, but just making sure.

Comment: I'm just trying to send the app to my device without being part of the developer program, which is what I said in the question.

Comment: Oh, unfortunately this isn't possible. If you want to run your app on any iOS device, you will need to enroll in the iOS developer program. https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

Answer (score 0):

You must have a valid provisioning profile, which requires enrollment in the iOS Developer Program. There is no way to run apps on an iOS device without a provisioning profile. For more information: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

Comment: I don't think this is true. If you search around, most people do this with a jailbroken device just fine. I have just run into an issue with it working on my iPad.

Comment: Assuming your device is jailbroken, I think you can use this: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile I have not done it myself, and I don't know how ethical or legally acceptable it is to do it like that, but I'll let you take it from here. (I think it's well worth the $99 for the developer program, though, to know you are doing it properly and to spare you from a lot of extra work.)